# Virtual box host-only network interface error

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, drivers

So I recently updated VirtualBox to the newest version (5.1.28). Everything was okay, then I installed a Windows update. This might have conflicted with my drivers or something.

**The error message:**

Could not find Host Interface Networking driver! 
Please reinstall. Resultaatcode:E_FAIL (0x80004005) 
Component:HostNetworkInterfaceWrap 
Interface:IHostNetworkInterface {455f8c45-44a0-a470-ba20-27890b96dba9}

What I already tried: 
- Run as administrator 
- Reinstalled VirtualBox, chose the 'repair' option - Reinstalled Card Reader driver

Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a card reader driver which is the problem but that the "Virtualbox Host Only" virtual network card in your system is missing. You may have seen this adapter in your Network Adapter Properties window before. My suggestion would be to completely uninstall VirtualBox, reboot, and then reinstall it.

When you remove and reinstall VirtualBox your VM list may start off empty again. Don't worry, you can re-add your VMs to the list by finding the .vbox file for each VM (usually stored in your user profile directory in a "VirtualBox VMs" subdirectory) and double clicking it, this will re-import the VM into VirtualBox.

Comment: My plan is to make a backup of the vm i'm currently working with and then reinstall and reboot. Thank you for your reaction.